# How to run a command with args on docker?

Tags: docker

This command "work"

```
docker exec -it slack1 '/usr/sbin/slackpkg'
```

of course without args show a little menu on stdout

This one return errorr

```
docker exec -it slack1 '/usr/sbin/slackpkg update'
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/sbin/slackpkg update": stat /usr/sbin/slackpkg update: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Fast question: how to run a command with args?

Comment: `docker exec -it slack1 /usr/sbin/slackpkg update`

Comment: This is the same difference as running `'slackpkg update'` and `slackpkg update` with or without quotes, without Docker.  Remember that anything you do in a `docker exec` command will be lost as soon as the container exits; consider putting this step in a Dockerfile instead.

Comment: Thanks, I usually use "" or '' when I run a command on "external" host, if you add this comment as answer I can close the question

Comment: I know the command is non-sense, I run only to learn command, I'm newbie with docker